# Word macro to go to a particular word count position?

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-count

I'm looking for a macro solution that will search for a particular word in the word count. Say I'm up to word 23,050 in a document (I work with book-length manuscripts) I would like to be able to go to that word. The normal go-to command will go to a line or a page but not a word. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub GoToWord(lWord As Long)
    ThisDocument.Words(lWord).Select
    Selection.Collapse
End Sub
```

The first command will select the desired word in the document, the second command will put the cursor at the beginning of that word. Note that the `Words`collection used includes punctuation marks.

Comment: I tried adding this in to my macros but it doesn't recognise it as a macro once it's added in. Is the syntax correct?

Comment: What do you mean by `it doesn't recognise it as a macro`? Do you mean that it does not show up in the Macros list on the Developer tab? That list only show Subs without parameters, and my example has a Long paramter. How do you plan to start the macro?